# Как изменить цвет нажатия optionsmenu?

Tags: android, java

Добрый вечер!
Я нашел способ, как поменять цвет optionsmenu в любой активити. Это делается созданием **style**

```
<style name="Theme_menu" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <item name="android:panelFullBackground">@drawable/background_menu</item>           
        </style>
```

Но цвет нажатия остается стандартным, а хочется поменять и его. 
Я понимаю, что имеется какой-то цвет, который отвечает за это нажатие, но вот как его задать.
Я перепробовал различные

*Сейчас вот так*
[image: сейчас вот так]

*А хочется вот так*
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем проблема решилась следующим образом:
Сделал отлов нажатия на меню, а по нажатию кнопки сделал показ **PopupWindow**, стилизовав полностью под меню.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `Selector`. Док: [Drawable Resources](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Создайте файл в папке drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_blue_down" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_blue_down" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_blue_down" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_blue"></item>
```

</selector>

Затем нужному итему в icon установите этот файл.

Comment: если бы было все так просто, я бы не обратился сюда, если вы сделаете пример, который будет работать, как вы предложили, то я вам буду очень признателен